# How do I accept pull requests on gerrit?

Tags: git, gerrit

I am using gerrit for code review. I have done the commit and I went to the UI and it says that the commit is "open" how do I accept that pull in order for it to merge with my official repo?

Answer (score 1):

Basic process:

1. You add reviewer(s) for your change
2. The reviewer(s) check your change and suggest improvements
3. You amend your change
4. The steps 2 and 3 are repeated until the code is approved
5. You submit the change

See more info [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/intro-quick.html).

Comment: Is approval necessary for the merge? Can't i merge my own pull request without reviewers, if i own the repository?

Comment: By default, changes need to be approved (+2) to be merged and the change owner can approve their own changes, but Gerrit (each repository) can be configured to work differently if desired.